# How do I condense text and a list into one line of code?

Tags: python

My current code looks like this:

```
list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

print("The first three items in the list are: ")

print(*list[0:3], sep=', ')
```

I'm wondering how I can combine the two prints into one print?

Comment: `print( "The first three items in the list are:", ', '.join(list[:3]) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

**Code:**

```py
list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

print(f"The first three items in the list are: {', '.join(list[0:3])}")
```

**Output:**

```
The first three items in the list are: A, B, C
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The code works!  I appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks. If you like this answer then please mark this as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answers from @sabil and @timroberts are good. Sometimes brute force has its advantages. In this case, maybe the print statement gets a little long.

```
mylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
print(f'The first three items in the list are: {mylist[0]}, {mylist[1]}, and {mylist[2]}')
```

You can also provide print with many many arguments and they will all be printed:

```
mylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
print('The first three items in the list are: ', mylist[0], ',',
      mylist[1], ', and ', mylist[2])
```

Notice that I've renamed your variable `list` to `mylist`. `list` is a reserved keyword in Python and you can run into trouble if you use it as a variable name. For example, let's say later in your code you wanted to convert a range into a list using the `list()` function. It won't work because `list` was already reassigned to a variable.

```
mylist2 = list(range(4))
```

Comment: Great point!  I'll never use "list" as a variable name from now on.